Executing external function inside of chrome.scripting.executeScript
how can I execute updateFunc function in the chrome.scripting.executeScript?
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    func: scrapData,
    args: [
      variable1,
      variable2,
      updateFunc, // <- here it's external function
    ],
  });

const scrapExperience = (variable1, variable2, updateFunc) => {
   console.log('works?')

   const variable3 = updateFunc(variable1, variable2);
   if (variable3) { 
      // do something
   }
}

If I try to execute this code -> it simply freezes and nothing proceeds.
console.log also not working.
Here we have an example - but this function returns some value, I need to execute function in the chrome.scripting.executeScript

try Serializling updateFunc to string - updateFunc.toString() and then again in scrapExperience function deserialize it like this const updateFunc = eval((${updateFuncString}));

Not working, still freezes
